# How to use preg_match in php?

Tags: php, html, forms, validation, preg-match

I want to create a form validation and I want to make sure that users won't enter any dangerous codes in the textboxes so I want to use `preg_match` to do that.
What I don't like users to type is (something instead of words from a-z , words from A-Z and numbers).
Now how can I use `preg_match` here?

Comment: If you just want to get familiar with regex than I highly recommend this page for playing around: https://regex101.com/

Comment: Did you do any research? Lazy question!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This regex will only allow letters and numbers.

```
/^[A-Z\d]+$/i
```

used in preg_match

```
if(preg_match('/^[A-Z\d]+$/i', $string)) {
      echo 'Good';
} else {
     echo 'Bad';
}
```

Regex101 demo: https://regex101.com/r/wH4uQ3/1

The `^` and `$` require the whole string match (they are anchors). The `[]` is a character class meaning any character inside is allowed. The `+` means one or more of the preceding character/group (this is known as a quantifier). The `A-Z` is a range that the character class understands to be letters `a-z`. `\d` is a number. The `/`s are delimiters telling where the regex starts and ends. The `i` is a modifier making the regex case insensitive (could remove that and add `a-z` so lowercase letters are allowed as well).

PHP Demo: https://eval.in/486282

Note PHP demo fails because whitespace isn't allowed. To allow white space add `\h` or `\s` in the character class (the `s` includes `\h` so no need for both; `\h` is for horizontal spaces.).

Answer (score -1):

Here is a simple example:

you can check more out at: http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php

You can also do this:    `$email = htmlspecialchars($_POST['email']);`

```
$email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
  $emailErr = "Invalid email format"; 
}
```